# rosdep out of date on armhf

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, rosdep, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The armfh python-rosdep package appears to be out of date in the package list. [1] The current version appears to be built [2] but it is simply not being pushed out to users via 'apt-get update'.

[1] http://packages.ros.org/ahendrix-mirror/ubuntu/lists/update-ahendrix-precise_precise_main_armhf_Packages
[2] http://packages.ros.org/ahendrix-mirror/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rosdep/

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78631/rosdep-out-of-date-on-armhf/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: that repository is updated manually whenever I push a release, and is frozen.

Can you elaborate on *why* having an out-of-date version of rosdep is a problem?

As a workaround you may be able to add the main ROS repository to your sources and install the version from upstream. If that doesn't work, you should be able to download the updated deb directly and install it with dpkg.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-20**:
It appears the file format has changed which causes rosdep update to fail. (FWIW, I've upgraded to Raring so this no longer affects me at least. :)